# Is there a way to ask general questions within the Stack app?

Tags: support, apps

I just joined Stack Exchange and am using the Android app called "Stack for Stack Overflow" by Tyler Wong. When I try to post a question, I'm forced to select from a number of topic categories. Is there a way to just ask a general question, not topic specific? Similar to something like AskReddit.

Comment: The Stack Exchange Network consists of several sites which can and have defined their scope. There is no site within the network that accepts a "general" question. We're more than happy that AskReddit takes those questions for us, so we don't have to. I praise the app maker that they try to enforce the topicality guidance that exists for sites in the SE network.